# Why is Chrome calling the autocompleted url before validation?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I'm using an API on my website to send emails to the users and while testing my call I noticed I was receiving the email twice.

So the url looks like `"localhost/api/sendEmail"` and, at least on Chrome, when I'm on localhost and I start typing `"/ap"` the url is automatically completed.

And I can see on Fiddler that Chrome (well I think that's him) is actually calling it before I press Enter so the mail is sent, and when I press Enter it is of course sent a second time.

This is not a problem since it won't be directly callable by the end-user, but I was just wondering what is the purpose of this first call ? Is Chrome pre-calling the page to make it faster to load ? Can it cause problems in different situations? Can one prevent Chrome from behaving like this?

Again, not a problem at all, but I'm just wondering.

Comment: Same issue with me. Just executes by it's self. Hope someone answers.

Comment: Same issue here with a dev url (localhost) too.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you have an API method that creates something, like new data or an email then it should be a POST request. This is good REST and also lets browsers and search engines know that the method has side effects and that it should not be called automatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is Google's `prefetch` feature, which loads the page quicker, assuming you execute the auto-completed URL.

You can disable this option in **Google Chrome**:

```
Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy: (uncheck) Prefetch resources..
```

Comment: They've renamed the setting to "Preload pages for faster browsing and searching".

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2019**

I came across [a similar question on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/394562/573965), which I provided [an updated answer](https://superuser.com/a/1405804/573965) for.

---

- **Disable page load prediction service**

`chrome://settings/` -> expand Advanced section

[image]

---

- **Disable NoState Prefetch**

`chrome://flags` -> search for "nostate"

[image]