# Flask and Chrome: route accessed without Enter

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask

I need help on a behavior of Chrome that I cannot explain. 
I don't know the proper terms to google and any pointer is welcome.

In Flask I defined a route `@app.route('/add/<page_id>')`

On Chrome address bar, when a valid address has been typed (i.e. `0.0.0.0:5050/add/id101`) the corresponding function is called **BEFORE** pressing Enter.

On Firefox this doesn't happen, and nothing is done till the Enter.

Is there a way to set Flask to avoid this behavior, without the need to change the browser's settings?

Comment: if it's something with the chrome, you can't fix it with flask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Chrome behavior. Not Flask related. You can't do anything within Flask. (see [Why is Chrome calling the autocompleted url before validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036730/why-is-chrome-calling-the-autocompleted-url-before-validation))